# Fatal error: Call to a member function setAccessToken() on a non-object in

Tags: php

I'm getting:

Fatal error: Call to a member function setAccessToken() on a non-object in

In this line:

```
$fbObj->setAccessToken($token->access_token);
```

And this is the function:

```
  public function setAccessToken($accessToken)
  {

     $this->accessToken = $accessToken;

  }
```

Where's the error?

Thanks  a lot

Comment: How do you initialize `$fbObj`?

Comment: I'm sorry I did not included it here but $fsObj is outside of any methods and it's like this: $fsObj = new EpiFoursquare($clientId, $clientSecret); 
Also setAccessToken($accessToken) is inside of class EpiFoursquare. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems $fbObj is not properly initialized, where are you using this line?

If you are using it inside a method, and the $fbObj is defined in the global scope (i.e. you defined it in an include file) you should use `global $fbObj` at the start of the method.

Comment: In sorry I did not included it here but $fsObj is outside of any methods and it's like this: $fsObj = new EpiFoursquare($clientId, $clientSecret);

Comment: Also setAccessToken($accessToken) is inside of class EpiFoursquare. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

create the object of class. `$fbObj` does not exists

```
$fbObj = new className();
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be like that

```
// get facebook library 

require_once 'library/facebook.php';


// Create our Application instance 
//normally we use $facebook instead of $fbobj

$fbobj = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret,
  'cookie' => true,
));
```

thn do other works